# howto pass json to docker solc

Tags: python, docker, solidity

I used to compile my solidity contracts with compile_standard in python, but it's getting very hard to keep up with the different compiler versions. After migrating to a new system, the new compiler won't work with older contracts.
So I figured, let's do it with docker,so I can choose my compiler version, how hard can it be, right? I tried to add a string as an argument, which would be my preferred way of working, but this doesn't work. If I try to use files, I get: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory, which makes sense, I guess, since I don't mount any paths on docker, since according to the solc docs, this is not necessary. But I can't find more information [here](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.6/installing-solidity.html#docker).

So my questions are;
1 if using files, how to pass the path?

2 is it possible to pass the json as a string and get a string back as a result?

```
compile_json = {
        "language": "Solidity",
        "sources": sources,
        "settings":
        {
            "outputSelection": {
                "*": {
                    "*": [
                        "metadata", "evm.bytecode"
                        , "evm.bytecode.sourceMap"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    }

    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:

        json.dump(compile_json, outfile)

    
    docker_cmd = 'docker run ethereum/solc:0.6.10 --standard-json < ' + self.base_path + 'data.json --allow-paths '+ self.base_path +' < out.json'

    bincode = subprocess.check_output([docker_cmd]).decode('utf-8')
```

edit:

```
docker_cmd = 'docker run ethereum/solc:0.6.0 --standard-json < ' + self.base_path + 'data.json --allow-paths '+ self.base_path +' > out.json'

try:
     bincode = subprocess.check_output(docker_cmd,shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode('utf-8')

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
```

I've managed to get it working through docker, but now solc complains about the json format:

{"errors":[{"component":"general","formattedMessage":"* Line 2, Column 1\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\n* Line 1, Column 1\n  A valid JSON document must be either an array or an object value.\n","message":"* Line 2, Column 1\n  Syntax error: value, object or array expected.\n* Line 1, Column 1\n  A valid JSON document must be either an array or an object value.\n","severity":"error","type":"JSONError"}]}

Comment: You seem to be having similar problems as the user in https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11543 so taking a look at the discussion in the issue might be helpful. Also, you're linking to 0.8.6 docs and that section was slightly tweaked in 0.8.7 to clarify that mounting volumes is still necessary if the JSON file is not self-contained.

Comment: By the way, if all you want is to be able to run arbitrary compiler versions, you can easily get binaries for all platforms from https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin/. They're statically linked so they should work pretty much anywhere. Even the docker image relies on this - the only file inside it is the static compiler binary.

Comment: I ended up compiling solidity files directly, as described in the manual, instead of using json files, which works.